# PredicateBuilder producing incorrect SQL statements

Tags: sql, linq, predicate, predicatebuilder

So I'm using LINQKIT found [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

And I'm trying to create an expression on one of my columns, CID.

The predicate looks like this:

```
Dim cid As String = "11R"

Dim predicate = PredicateBuilder.[New](Of uv_Manifest).And(Function(x) x.CID = cid)
```

And it returns a predicate which looks like this:

```
{x => (CompareString(x.CID, value(FSVendor_RefactoredRepository.ManifestManager+_Closure$__2-0).$VB$Local_cid, False) == 0)}
```

This returns SQL which looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CID] AS [CID], 
    FROM (SELECT 
    [uv_Manifest].[CID] AS [CID],   
    FROM [dbo].[uv_Manifest] AS [uv_Manifest]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[CID] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[CID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

When I run this statement in visual studio it times out, whereas if I hardcode the predicate to be like this:

```
Dim predicate = PredicateBuilder.[New](Of uv_Manifest).And(Function(x) x.CID = "11R")
```

It works fine and gives me a predicate which looks like this:

```
{x => (CompareString(x.CID, "11R", False) == 0)}
```

And the SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CID] AS [CID]
    FROM (SELECT 
    [uv_Manifest].[CID] AS [CID]
    FROM [dbo].[uv_Manifest] AS [uv_Manifest]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE '11R' = [Extent1].[CID]
```

And it executes fine.

Here is my line of LINQ:

```
Dim q = webDataContext.uv_Manifest.AsExpandable().Where(filters)
```

Why is it when I change the value to be hardcoded it works as expected but when I don't it doesn't create the correct SQL statement and how do I fix this?

Comment: In SQL `col = NULL` is `UNKNOWN` That is why it creates `OR (([Extent1].[CID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))`

Comment: So at that point it doesnt know what the cid is anymore right?

Comment: Holy crap that's a lot of effort to write a simple SQL script. I don't understand the purpose of this software. Sorry I don't have the answer though!

Comment: We're using entity framework

Comment: Right - when the framework doesn't know that the value of `cid` is non-null, it must add the additional test to handle that case. That is no reason for the SQL to timeout, however. BTW, that isn't a function of PredicateBuilder but rather of EF.